# O lobo rouba ou procura comida?

Tags: uso-de-palavras, verbos, diferenças, significado-em-contexto

Eu vi uma frase como a seguinte:

> **O lobo cinza está roubando para comer na campina.**

Pode ser ***o lobo cinza está procurando ...***?

Comment: como está no gerundio, pode dar o entender do mesmo significado....mas eu usaria outro verbo, como caçando...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não, *roubar* e *procurar* são coisas diferentes. Eu encontrei a primeira das tuas frase [neste *Learn Portuguese*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22O%20lobo%20cinza%20est%C3%A1%20roubando%20para%20comer%20na%20campina.%20The%20gray%20wolf%20is%20foraging%20for%20food%22&oq=%22O%20lobo%20cinza%20est%C3%A1%20roubando%20para%20comer%20na%20campina.%20The%20gray%20wolf%20is%20foraging%20for%20food%22&aqs=chrome..69i57.4042j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), aparentemente como tradução de:

> The gray wolf is foraging for food in the meadow

A tradução correta desta frase é como tu sugeres:

> O lobo cinzento está **procurando** comida na campina.

Ou então, numa tradução menos literal, como sugere o Peixoto acima, *está caçando na campina*. A outra frase — “lobo está roubando para comer” — é um pouco estranha e é possivelmente um tradução errada da frase em inglês. Literalmente, significa que o lobo está comendo animais que pertencem a alguém ou que outros predadores caçaram. Mas *roubar para comer* tem normalmente um significado específico, mas nós costumamos dizer isso acerca de pessoas, não de lobos. Imagina:

> O homem está roubando para comer.

Isto significa que homem não tem dinheiro para comprar comida e rouba comida porque tem fome; ou rouba dinheiro ou objetos para poder comprar comida. E nós normalmente acrescentamos o *para comer* para desculpar um pouco o homem, porque roubar para comer é considerado menos grave que roubar por outros motivos.

Também é possível dizer isto acerca de lobos. Se o lobo, por exemplo, matar uma ovelha do João, naturalmente que é para ele comer, e nós podemos dizer que o lobo roubou uma ovelha ao João; e “roubou para comer”: coitado, estava com fome, não tem culpa. Mas seria mais natural dizer simplesmente que o lobo matou (ou comeu) uma ovelha ao João.